# Reporting the relationship of a log-log regression as increase

Tags: stata

I am reporting the results of a log-log linear regressions in Stata and want to automate the report of my results as much as possible to make it reproducible. For easier interpretation, I want to report the results of my coefficients as % increase in X. Based on [Kenneth Benoit's pdf](https://kenbenoit.net/assets/courses/me104/logmodels2.pdf) and [Dimitry's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93089/reporting-regression-statistics-after-logarithmic-transformation) answer on SO, I have computed the interpretation as follows for a MRE based on Wooldridge Introductory to Econometrics.

```
* Load data from Woolridge
bcuse hprice2.dta, clear
* Generate the logged variable for the distance
gen ldist = ln(dist)
* Run the regression
regress lprice lnox ldist rooms stratio
* Transform the estimate for easier transportation
nlcom exp(_b[lnox]*ln(1.10))
```

Based on the transformation, my interpretation is that a 10% increase in the `nox` is associated with a reduction of the `price` of approximately 9%.

Is this the correct and easiest way to do this in Stata?